# I Get Error: Variable Not In Scope for very simple Haskell Code

Tags: haskell

I just learn Haskell for 2 days and when i did some practice just like the example in the book, i found my self an error, even for very simple code.

Here is the code:

```
doubleMe x = x + x
```

this is super simple code, but every time when i want to execute it inside VS Code i get an error like this

```
<interactive>:2:1: error:
Variable not in scope: doubleMe :: t0 -> t
```

I tried execute this simple code in Ghci by put "let" in front of doubleMe, it can work, but every time i save in the source file and execute in in VSCode, i got error.

Any help would be appreciate. Because i dont want to stop learning just because of this error.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Hendrik! Can you post which VS Code Haskell extensions you are using, and the *exact* sequence of actions you take to execute it?

Comment: You can run the script also in ghci with ghci <filename> and then just call doubleMe

Comment: now it's fixed. I make a new file and put same example. i can execute it now.

Comment: It looks like you did not load the file in the (updated) `ghci` interpreter.

Comment: Haskell isn't really designed as a scripting language like Python,  where you work in the REPL a lot. Haskell is a compiled language, and the GHCi interpreter does things a bit differently from the compiler. To be precise, everything in GHCi is being done in the IO monad, but you won't have learned about that yet. So unlike Python you can't just type a program into the REPL and expect it to work.

Comment: If you're in GHCi, you need `let` before the assignment. The entire session is running its own quasi-monad

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to run it, code should have `main` function, for example

```
doubleMe x = x + x

main = print $ doubleMe 2
```

Not tried it, VSCode suggests to use `Haskell GHCi Debug Adapter Phoityne` extension. As far as I can see, it may take some time to configure it.

Try to use more simple way:

1. Create a file DoubleMe.hs somewhere

   ```
    module DoubleMe where

    doubleMe x = x + x
   ```
2. Move to folder where this file exists.
3. In console type `ghci` and press `Enter`.
4. Then type `:l DoubleMe.hs` and press `enter` to load our module.
5. Now function `doubleMe` is in scope and you can call it from console.